# how do call a class(mapview extending mapActivity) from another class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I tried doing it by using Intent,but,i seem to get the following error:
11-15 22:40:39.266: ERROR/dalvikvm(1589): Could not find class 'BlobCity.xyz.com.maps', referenced from method BlobCity.xyz.com.BlobCity$sendUserPass.onClick

where blobcity is my class that calls the maps class which contains the mapview.

Comment: Hi, calling a class is basic oo programing AClass a = new AClass(); a.something();. Are you more trying to launch another application on the phone ?

Comment: no,they are two different files...i tried using intent...but to no avail...is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a classloading or similar issue.  It seems to be saying that one compiled Java class ("BlobCity.xyz.com.BlobCity.sendUserPass") contains a static dependency on another class ("BlobCity.xyz.com.maps"), but the class loader (or something) couldn't find the class file for the latter class.

(By the way, your choice of class and package names is pretty awful.  You should try to stick to the standard naming conventions if you want other people to be able to understand your code.

- All class names ... including nested class names should be in "CamelCase".
- Package names should be all lowercase.
- Hierarchical package names should in reverse domain name order; e.g. "com.xyz.blobcity".
- You shouldn't use a random domain name without some kind of permission / authorization ... and there's no way that I'll believe that you work for "xyz.com"!)

Comment: so other than the naming conventions, is there any solution to this?

Comment: The solution is to make sure that you make **all** of your classes available to the classloader ... not just "BlobCity.xyz.com.BlobCity".  I'm not an Android developer, so I cannot tell you *how* you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
<application ...>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    ...
    ...
</application>
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml, I have the same problem before and adding `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` solve the problem